Cannot find newly created AWS SQS Queues due to pagination
When creating new AWS SQS queues in an account with too many existing queues, I find that the newly created queues can't be found in either the AWS console or via the CLI list-queues command. I believe this issue is related to how AWS handles pagination. This issue also affects selecting queues in the Lambda UI, such as when assigning a DLQ.
I know using Terraform is an option, but sometimes I just need to create a queue quickly for testing. Is there a more direct method to locate these new queues?

If you can't find an SQS queue after creation, then perhaps you are looking in the wrong region.

@jarmod Hi I can see it directly through the queue's URL, and it's in the same region. The thing that bothers me is that I cannot select it from other services (like setting it as the DLQ for lambda from the dropdown selection)

Update: I finally found a solution.
If you want to make sure that your newly created queue appears, you can name the queue with a prefix that starts with the letter "a". This will make sure the queue is included in the initial set of results returned by pagination


I know using Terraform is an option, but sometimes I just need to create a queue quickly for testing

Yes, use the AWS CLI tool
Or create a script using one of the AWS SDKs
